# "How many maximum... " or "What is the maximum..."

Tags: grammar, questions

I just came across a chemistry question in class which says:

> "How many maximum spectral lines are possible if the electron belongs to the 4th shell?"

I wonder if the question is grammatically correct? Shouldn't this be something like:

> "What is the maximum number of spectral lines possible if the electron belongs to the 4th shell?"

Is 'how many maximum' correct? Could you kindly explain the difference between "how many maximum" and "what is the maximum". And is there some kind of grammar rules relating this?

And my own example:

> 1. How many maximum people can fit in this room?
>    OR
> 2. What is the maximum number of people that can fit in this room?

(I know we can remove the maximum without changing the meaning much but I am wondering how to use maximum in these type of sentences)

Thank you.

Comment: It's as you suggest! In the first example **maximum** attempts unnecessarily and awkwardly to emphasise the number possible.

Comment: The original question might be grammatically correct; much more context is needed including knowledge of chemistry. The question may assume that there are several maximum spectral lines as well as many other spectral lines that are not maximums. Your own example 1 is incorrect, and 2 is correct. Leaving out maximum in your example 2 does change the normal meaning.  Without maximum you would usually be referring to the room in its normal configuration, and with maximum you would be asking about the upper limit of its capacity.

Comment: Thank you very much @Peter and @ RonaldSole